# how to report commission (tag 12) across multiple partial fills

Tags: fix-protocol

If a large order is executed as a series of partial fills, what is the customary way to report the commission field value in the Execution Reports (tag 12)?
Do I report the same total commission value in every partial fill?  Do I report commission as 0 in every partial fill except for the last one where the LeavesQty is now 0 and ExecType is FILLED?  I am thinking that if reporting commission is left for the very last partial fill ER, what if the order is not executed 100% and the client eventually cancels the remaining qty -- then the customer never learns the commission charged.
I have searched the FIX protocol specs, couldnt find anything.
Thank you